# printing collections: variable specific

Tags: scala

I have multidimensional arrays where the dimensions are saved in an `ArrayBuffer`.

When I print it, obviously, I get e.g. `ArrayBuffer(2, 2, 3)`, but I would like to have `2x2x3`. I know that I can do it as follows `println(multiarray.dim.mkString("x"))`.

Is there any "magical" way that I get `2x2x3` by simply issuing `println(multiarray.dim)`?

**EDIT**

`dim` is method of the multidimensional arrays that gives the dimensions...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `dim` returns an ArrayBuffer, then, no, you can't just use `println(multiarray.dim)`.  Here are some simple alternatives though:

1. **Define a method to return the dimensions as a String (in your multiarray class):**

   ```
   def dimStr = dim mkString "x"
   ```
2. **Define a utility method for printing:**

   ```
   def printdim(buffer: ArrayBuffer[Int]) = println(buffer mkString "x")
   // or
   def printdim(multiarray: MultiArray) = println(multiarray.dim mkString "x")
   ```

**Generalizing toString:**

With a bit more effort, you can define a version of `println` that will work the way you'd like.  The idea is to abstract the String-creation logic. The power of this approach is that, once the basic infrastructure is in place, you're able to control the "stringification" of any type just by bringing an appropriate implicit into scope.

Start by defining a type class:

```
trait Stringable[T] extends (T => String)
```

Provide a default implementation of the type class (which just falls back on the ordinary `toString` method):

```
class DefaultStringable[T] extends Stringable[T] { 
   def apply(x: T) = x.toString
}
object DefaultStringable {
   implicit def any2stringable[T]: Stringable[T] = new DefaultStringable[T]
}
```

Implement the type class for your use case:

```
implicit object DimIsStringable extends Stringable[ArrayBuffer[Int]] {
   def apply(buf: ArrayBuffer[Int]) = buf mkString "x"
}
```

Define a print method that uses the type class:

```
def myprintln[T](x: T)(implicit e: Stringable[T]) = e(x)
```

Fun.

```
import DefaultStringable._
myprintln(ArrayBuffer(1,2,3)) // prints "ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3)"
```

Profit!

```
import DimIsStringable._
myprintln(ArrayBuffer(1,2,3)) // prints "1x2x3"
```

If desired, you can make the default type class always available without requiring any import. To do so, you provide the conversion in a companion module to the Stringable trait (as demonstrated below).  The disadvantage of doing so is that you'll no longer have a compiler error to alert you if you forget to import an appropriate Stringable.

```
object Stringable {
   implicit def any2stringable[T]: Stringable[T] = new DefaultStringable[T]
}
```

Comment: @Aaron Novstrup I really like your approach, as I might need to print other variables specifically. But what if I have also some `ArrayBuffer`s that I want to print as `ArrayBuffer(1,2,3)`? Is it possible to restrict to the `dim` only?

Comment: One of the advantages of this approach is that you control how a given type will be converted to a String by importing an appropriate conversion into scope.  But once you import an implicit `Stringable[SomeType]`, everything of type `SomeType` has to use that conversion or you must explicitly pass the conversion you want to use: `myprintln(ArrayBuffer(1,2,3))(DefaultStringable)`.

Comment: You could define a Stringable[MultiArray], though. Or have `dim` return a type that contains an `ArrayBuffer`, and define a Stringable for that type.

Comment: I said "everything of type `SomeType`" above. That should have been "everything of type `SomeType` _within the scope of the import_".  It can be as local as you like, even just within a particular method or block.

Comment: Am I missing something really obvious here?  In python (and probably js) I would override the toString method on the ArrayBuffer in the places where it's used as a set of dimensions. In Scala I'd put `{ def toString = xxx }` right after the `new ArrayBuffer` whenever I use it as dimensions, no?

Comment: @codewarrior ArrayBuffers are often not created via the constructor (from the client's point of view).  In particular, many of the collection methods (`map`, `filter`, etc.) return a new ArrayBuffer.  Of course, there is the possibility of extending ArrayBuffer to avoid this problem, but it's not a simple matter.

Answer (score 3):

I m' not sure that would qualify as magical, but would that be ok?

```
class ArrayDim extends ArrayBufer[Int] {
   override def toString = mkString ("x")
}
```

Edit : 
Then in the code of your multidimensional array class, 
replace `dim = new ArrayBuffer` by `dim = new ArrayDim`. Depending on how you fill the buffer, you may need minor changes in the code.

Comment: @didierd I have done as you have suggested (`var dim = dim.asInstanceOf[ArrayDim]`) but I get the following error: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer cannot be cast to ArrayDim.

Comment: I may have missed what you do in your multidimensional array. What I meant was create an ArrayDim instead of creating an ArrayBuffer. See Edit.

Comment: A problem with the subclassing approach is that you lose the literal syntax for constructing `ArrayBuffer`s. For example, this won't work: `val x = ArrayDim(5,5,5)`. Another problem is that operations like `map` on ArrayDim will return an ArrayBuffer. For these reasons, I like the implicit conversion approach suggested by mpilquist. But that seems to work only for adding non-existing methods, not overriding existing methods.

Comment: the implicit does not solve the problem as I understood it, but not sure I understood it right. I tried to ensure that dim would be displayed properly however far it may be passed in code. All of your criticisms are correct (but allowing ArrayDim(5,5,5) is easy. Making it a

Comment: (continued) Making ArrayDim a full fledged collection, with type-preserving operations, sounds like much too much work just to fix toString. This is sort of shot in the dark having to guess how the multidimensional array is coded and how clients use and print dim.

Comment: @didierd I wish extending collections was simpler (actually I am aready doing it for the multidimensional arrays)!!!I would like to avoid a full fledged subclassing just to fix `toString`. I will rework the code to use `ArrayDim`...

Answer (score 1):

You can use an implicit conversion to something that has a dim method.  Here's an example:

```
scala> implicit def toDim(t: Traversable[_]) = new { def dim = t.mkString("x") }
toDim: (t: Traversable[_])java.lang.Object{def dim: String}

scala> List(1, 2, 3).dim
res0: String = 1x2x3

scala> ArrayBuffer(2, 2, 3).dim
res1: String = 2x2x3
```

Comment: I may have misinterpreted the question.  If you already have a dim method that returns an ArrayBuffer of dimensions, then you could just override toString as didierd suggests.

Comment: You could rename the "pimped" method to `dimStr`. The final syntax would be `println(multiarray.dim.dimStr)`; not exactly what the question asked for, but not too bad. I like that it makes the intent clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can define println locally, overriding the imported defintion, if you wish:

```
def println(a : Any) = System.out.println(a match {
  case seq : Seq[_] => seq.mkString("x")
  case a@_ => a
}

println(scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer(1,2,3)) // yields 1x2x3
println("Hello") //yields "Hello"
```

Unfortunately this won't condition on the type of variable inside the Seq. There might be a way to do that, though I'm not sure since we can't require that a has a Manifest. Will have a think.

Comment: Ah, I failed to notice the '.dim' that you were using. Indeed, since this doesn't exist, you can use an implicit definition as mpilquist suggests.